# gdb pass raw result of evaluation to custom python function

Tags: python, gdb

amd64, register `$rdi` is a pointer to `"/home/il/gammu-git/src/gammu/libgammu/tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0"`

Seen here an example:

```
define foo
py print gdb.execute("output $arg0", to_string=True).strip('"')
end
```

expected:

```
(gdb) foo (char*)$rdi
/home/il/gammu-git/src/gammu/libgammu/tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
```

However, the `output` command also prints the address of the string:

```
(gdb) foo (char*)$rdi
0x7fffffffe180 "/home/il/gammu-git/src/gammu/libgammu/tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gdb syntax is a mess, worse than the command line of MS-DOS.

With 6 "simple" steps you can pass arbitrary string to python:

```
define foo
    # reset convenience var., or get 'Too many array elements'
    set $foo_arg0 = 0
    # $arg0 expanded too early, can't use it directly in python
    set $foo_arg0 = $arg0
    #
    # parse_and_eval() affected by print settings, wtf?
    #
    # don't print address of a string
    set print addr off
    # print long string
    set print elements 0
    # get rid of '<repeats n times>'
    set print repeats unlimited
    #
    # parse_and_eval() returns quoted string. Unquote with eval
    py s = eval(str(gdb.parse_and_eval("$foo_arg0")))
    py print s
end

(gdb) foo "abc"
abc
(gdb) foo $val
def
(gdb) foo (char*)$rdi
/home/il/gammu-git/src/gammu/libgammu/tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by doing it in python, i.e.

```
py print gdb.execute("output $arg0", to_string=True).strip('"').split()[1]
```

or (and that's what I'd prefer) probably by customizing your `output` call. `gdb` has comprehensive online help by typing in `help output` and following the leads there:

```
(gdb) help output
Like "print" but don't put in value history and don't print newline.
This is useful in user-defined commands.
(gdb) help print
Print value of expression EXP.
Variables accessible are those of the lexical environment of the selected
stack frame, plus all those whose scope is global or an entire file.

$NUM gets previous value number NUM.  $ and $$ are the last two values.
$$NUM refers to NUM'th value back from the last one.
Names starting with $ refer to registers (with the values they would have
if the program were to return to the stack frame now selected, restoring
all registers saved by frames farther in) or else to debugger
"convenience" variables (any such name not a known register).
Use assignment expressions to give values to convenience variables.

{TYPE}ADREXP refers to a datum of data type TYPE, located at address ADREXP.
@ is a binary operator for treating consecutive data objects
anywhere in memory as an array.  FOO@NUM gives an array whose first
element is FOO, whose second element is stored in the space following
where FOO is stored, etc.  FOO must be an expression whose value
resides in memory.

EXP may be preceded with /FMT, where FMT is a format letter
but no count or size letter (see "x" command).
(gdb) help x
Examine memory: x/FMT ADDRESS.
ADDRESS is an expression for the memory address to examine.
FMT is a repeat count followed by a format letter and a size letter.
Format letters are o(octal), x(hex), d(decimal), u(unsigned decimal),
  t(binary), f(float), a(address), i(instruction), c(char), s(string)
  and z(hex, zero padded on the left).
Size letters are b(byte), h(halfword), w(word), g(giant, 8 bytes).
The specified number of objects of the specified size are printed
according to the format.

Defaults for format and size letters are those previously used.
Default count is 1.  Default address is following last thing printed
with this command or "print".
```

**BY THE WAY**: should've mentioned this earlier, but: probably address printing is set to `on` for some reason. So:

```
set print addr off
```

will probably solve your issue.

Comment: I tried p/s and p/r , but the address is still printed

Comment: did you omit the `(char*)` cast when doing `/s` ?

Comment: Oh... I forgot to check one thing. I've updated my answer, at the bottom. Would you try?

Comment: Yes, that helps a little. Still have to split `$32 = "aaaa"` in python.

Comment: If python can't use gdb vars directly, maybe set env var?